# Neural Network By Rstudio

Tags: r, neural-networks, r-squared

I use R to run neural network model, but The Rsquared is too low. I have tried different learning rate, threshold and neurons but still the R-square is below 50%. Is there anything I can do to improve this condition?

My code:

```
formula.bpn<-Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6

bpn<-neuralnet(formula = formula.bpn, data = data, hidden = c(3), learningrate = 0.1, 
               threshold = 0.5, stepmax = 5e5)
smp.size<-floor(0.8*nrow(data))
set.seed(131)
train.ind<-sample(seq_len(nrow(data)),smp.size)
train<-data[train.ind,]
test<-data[-train.ind,]
model <- train(form=formula.bpn,data=train, 
               method="neuralnet",
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(.layer1=c(1:20), .layer2=c(0), .layer3=c(0)),
               learningrate = 0.5,threshold = 0.5,stepmax = 5e5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RMSE doesn't seem to improve for larger networks and beyond a layer size of 4 your $R^2$ doesn't improve much, that means that layer size isn't what is limiting performance.

Neural networks are hard to train, any of your hyper-parameters could be what is limiting performance. We can suggest what might be the problem but really the only way to know is if you test out different values of hyperparameters. You don't need to do a full gridsearch, changing one hyperparameter at a time can show which was most incorrect.

- Your threshold performance looks very high, maybe training is stopping too early.
- You have two learning rates in your code, 0.5 isn't absurdly high but it seems higher than normal, perhaps you should try a different rate.
- Stepmax is a normal size, I doubt the issue lies with that.

Comment: Do I need to normalize my data to make value of data between [0,1]? And what you mean the stepmax is a normal size?

Comment: @Jeffrey You do need to normalize inputs to either [0,1] or [-1,1] or to zero mean and unit variance; if you have outliers then unit variance is the best approach.  The value you chose for your stepmax is a typical value that is used so I don't think it is the cause of your low performance.

Comment: Sorry, bother you again, If I am going to do unit variance, I need to do Y variable and each X variable, right?

Comment: @Jeffrey you do need to do each X variable, doing each individually works well. You can also remove correlation between X variables in a process called whitening https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation. They Y variable also needs to be normalized but how to do it depends on your NN architecture. If you have a softmax output layer then all your Y variables need to be in the range [0,1]. Normalize Y so that it's easy for the output layer to match the target output.